# WPF - databinding controls in UserControl to class members within the same UC (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

How can I databind the controls within my usercontrol to a class instance within the same UserControl in WPF/C#? 
For example if I move the slider the value of a certain class member should update. If I change the class or some value within it it should change in the UserControl.

More general question: What is the easiest way to create UserControl that edits and loads public fields of one class?

Edit:
Usercontrol

```
public partial class ThresholdingSettingsUC : UserControl
{
    public ThresholdingSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public ThresholdingSettingsUC ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();   
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ColonyCounterApp.ThresholdingSettingsUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="300"

         >

<Grid>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
        <GroupBox Header="Hue filter" Height="150" Name="gbHue" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox Content="Use hue filtering" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="cbHue" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </Grid>
        </GroupBox/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Class that should be bound to the control

```
public struct ThresholdingSettings:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public bool FilterHue {
        get
        { return filterHue; }
        set
        {
            if (filterHue==value)
            {
                return;
            }
            filterHue = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged ("FilterHue"); }
        }
    private bool filterHue;

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
    private void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
        {
            h (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ElementName` (I'm assuming you mean members on the user control itself).

```
class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}

<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Name="myUserControl"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Slider Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=myUserControl}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the class instance as the DataContext of your userControl and use the default bind mechanism with a relative Path.

To support two way binding (class updates UI, UI updates class) the class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged (or have the specified properties defined as DependencyProperty).

If you cant alter the Class code, you'll need to expose the required properties in the UserControl and invoke it's PropertyChanged event (to allow the UI to update) and update the instance with the new value

Comment: The class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, I still cannot find where to put the databinding...

Comment: `<Slider Value="{Binding Path=ClassPropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" />`
Assuming ClassPropertyName is the name of the instance's property you wish to bind to, and that you set the class instance as your UserControl's DataContext